# Visual Studio -.ASPX files take so much longer to load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am using VS 2010 i am accessing it through remote desktop but when i run some page it is taking alot of time to load,i dont know why is there any quick solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling intellitrace in VS2010. There are numerous posts online, discussing this behaviour in VS2010. One of the tips should help you.